# Promedio de horas PHP

Tags: php

Quiero sumar y sacar un promedio de unas horas.

```
$cadena = '00:09:00,00:09:00,00:09:00,00:09:00,00:09:00';
$arr = explode(",",$cadena);
$total = strtotime('00:00:00');

for($i = 0; $i<count($arr);$i++)
{
  $total = $total + strtotime($arr[$i]);
}

$total = $total / count($arr);
echo date('H:i:s',$total);
```

Esto me regresa 05:45:00 y yo esperaba 00:09:00.
Cuál fue el error :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php

$cadena    = '00:09:00,00:09:00,00:09:00,00:09:00,00:09:00';
$arreglo   = explode(",", $cadena);
$resultado = 0;

foreach($arreglo AS $tiempo)
{
    $resultado += strtotime($tiempo) - strtotime("TODAY") . "\n";
}

$resultado = $resultado / count($arreglo);

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $resultado);

?>
```

> Resultado:
>
> 00:09:00

Comment: No me sale! tengo esto

Comment: Podrias explicarte @AlbertoSiurob, no entiendo lo que me dices

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Que version de PHP estas usando?

Comment: Ya salío lo siento, Lo que sucedía era que, como la información viene de la base de datos, hay delimitaciones que no tienen valor, por ejemplo 00:09:00,,00:09:00. La delimitación que no se cubre se interpreta como NULL y eso me pasa a FLOAT el valor y gmdate() requiere un INT. Lo solucioné con IF. Gracias y saludos.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob Perfecto! Espero te sirva

Answer (score 5):

Cuando llamas a strtotime sin pasarle una fecha, asume la fecha actual, y el timestamp de hoy más nueve minutos no es lo mismo que el timestamp de T=0 más nueve minutos.

En particular, el timestamp 0 ocurrió el 31 de diciembre de 1969 a las 21:00 hrs, por lo que hay un desfase implícito de tres horas en cualquier strtotime. Eso tiene consecuencias tan extrañas como que

```
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime('00:00:00')+strtotime('00:09:00'));
```

Imprima

```
03:09:00
```

En tu caso, estás inicializando el total con un valor distinto de cero, por lo que el promedio de esa suma deja de tener sentido.

La solución de Iván Botero soluciona tu problema porque inicializa el total explícitamente en cero, y en cada iteración del bucle quita el delta de tiempo entre la fecha actual y el timestamp inicial del universo.

Answer (score 1):

si quieres sumar aqui esta esto espero que ayude

```
<?php
$hora="14:00";//horas
$sumar=10;//minutos

$segundos_horaInicial=strtotime($hora);

$segundos_minutoAnadir=$sumar*60;//segundos

$total=date("H:i",$segundos_horaInicial+$segundos_minutoAnadir);

echo "<br>".$total;
?>
```